# How to change static data in react-native to JSON-data submitted by form inside app

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow in my life so please don't roast me. In the images below I have static data put into my array, what I want to do is have a form on another page where people can add an event and once they press submit, on this page another event pops(the boxes) up with the form data.

[image: Image Description]

yes I know I can word it better but this is my first time so go easy

I have tried looking into the CRUD format, doing a to do list in which I have input text and then it adds to the list, I am just having trouble transferring this to the UI I already have. the data in the flatlist in the code takes the destinations array. I need the data not to take something static but coming from a input form.

```
renderDestinations = () => {
    return (
      <View style={[ styles.column, styles.destinations ]}>
        <FlatList
          horizontal
          pagingEnabled
          scrollEnabled
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          decelerationRate={0}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          snapToAlignment="center"
          style={{ overflow:'visible' }}
          data={this.props.destinations}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}`}
          onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: this.scrollX }} }])}
          renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderDestination(item)}
        />
        {this.renderDots()}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: You're basically asking about keeping state in your app. Did you read the [state section](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state) of the docs?

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state) you can use state to keep array of data like below:

```
state = {
   data: [{title: 'Picnic', location: 'Sweden'},{title: 'Drinks', location: 'Sweden'}]
}

<FlatList data={this.state.data} /> // ... And rest of your props
```